# Curve fitting from image or pdf

Tags: r, statistics, regression, curve-fitting, data-science

I have a bunch of images like this one [IGBT characteristics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Xqh.png), copied from pdf file . i am looking to extract data and do some curve fitting.

1. I tried manually Engauge Digitizer software to extract numeric data from image [IGBT Vce vs Ic @ Tvj three curve's data .csv files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1YSr9hMD_SBdlh6bmZ4WHpyV2c). You can see three curves in image, each curve is dependent on temperature Tvj. I need to fit equation for each curve as

Vce25 = a25*Ic + b25*log(Ic) + c25 ---(1) a25,b25,c25 are coefficients for Tvj = 25C,

similarly we can have Vce125 and Vce150 equations for temperature 125 & 150. I need combine these three curves as single equation { Vce = f(Ic,Tvj) } coefficients as temperature dependent. I need to estimate Vce at any given Ic and Tvj (eg: at Ic=200, Tvj=50C Vce=?), how to combine equations to make.

2. How to do do this in R?

Vce ->voltage, Ic  -> current, Tvj -> temperature

Comment: http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-FF1400R12IP4-DS-v02_04-en_de.pdf?fileId=db3a30431f848401011feb7645573e9f

Comment: thanks for your effort, i learned new technique converting pdf to svg and work in R.

Comment: The way to give thanks on SO is an upvote.

Comment: rephrased question. In the image you can see three curves, each curve is dependent on temperature. I need to estimate Vce at any given Ic and Tvj (eg: at Ic=200, Tvj=50C Vce=?). how buld regression model in R

Comment: It's still a bit vague regarding what is mean by a "regression model" but it is no longer as broad as it was because the data extraction process has been completed. (And the link to the software is why I'm upvoting.) I'm thinking a nonlinear optimization procedure to fit an exponential with 2 or three parameters might succeed if you could specify what class of model would be anticipated by whatever physical process might underly this data. (Doesn't appear to me to data that would be well fit by a linear regression model.)

Comment: you can see three curves, each curve is dependent on temperature Tvj. i  can have equation like Vce25 = a25*Ic + b25*log(Ic) + c25 ---(1) @ temperature Tvj=25C and for Tvj=125 & 150. I need to estimate Vce at any given Ic and Tvj (eg: at Ic=200, Tvj=50C Vce=?), how to combine equations to make temperature dependent.

Comment: You should edit the question, rather than using comments for clarification. That gives you better formatting capacity and improves the chances it will be reopened. It will )perhaps) also allow us to see whether a25 is the product of a and 25 or just a parameter name. You should not assume we share your domain notational conventions.

Comment: a25,b25 ,c25 are constants, rephrased question. reopen the question

Answer (score 1):

Use spline regression. You will need to read a set of [x,y] pairs off the image and pick some of these as knots for a piece-wise linear regression model. Refer the example below and follow instructions.

1. Get a representative set of [x, y] coordinates.
2. Identify knots and note x coordinates.
3. Construct a design matrix
4. Fit a piece-wise linear model
5. Plot

## 1: Get a representative set of [x, y] coordinates. For illustration purposes, I have generated [x, y] samples from a noisy sine-wave. You will need to read off the images.

```
# Make a noisy sine-waver over two cycles with 500 samples
n <- 500
x <- seq(0, 4*pi, length=n)
y <- sin(x) + rnorm(n, sd=0.33)
plot(x, y)
```

## 2: Identify knots and note x coordinates. I have used 12 knots to illustrate.

```
# Add 12 knots
knots <- seq(0, 4*pi, length=12)
```

## 3: Construct a design matrix

```
splineTerms <- sapply(knots, function(knot) (x > knot)*(x-knot))
designMatrix <- cbind(1, x, splineTerms)
```

## 4: Fit a piece-wise linear model

```
sticksModel <- lm(y ~ designMatrix - 1) # Intercept included in design
yHat <- predict(sticksModel)
```

## 5: Plot

```
plot(x, y, pch=21, col="blue", cex=2)
lines(x, yHat, col="red", lwd=4)
```

I have followed this process for thermocouples and other non-linear sensors and it works quite reliably.

Comment: I don't think this is useful in this case because of all the grid lines and other annotation. It might be a middle part of a strategy I n a much simpler case but there would be many extra steps for preparation.

Comment: Why down-vote? I am trying to help. - Sanjay

Comment: The interesting part is step one and you gloss over it.

Comment: The whole point of the question at least as I understood it is "how to get the x-y values _programatically_". You basically said that step should be done by "eyeball" and pencil and paper,  and my opinion is that was clearly not helpful.

Comment: thanks for your help, but this solution doesn't fit for my problem

Comment: With the revised question, this now appears to solve it. Reversing downvote.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that.